# How to update a pipeline variable after the task is succeeded, through `output variable` section or some other method in Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-deployment, azure-devops-extensions

I want to update a pipeline variable once my task is finished. Can I do it through output variable section provided in azure DevOps?

[image]

The main objective is to let downstream tasks know that the list of specific previous tasks have succeeded, which I can check by adding custom conditions.

[image]

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your tasks are in an agent job, there is no need to use the `output variable` section, just add a Powershell task after the successful task, you can overwrite/update the value of the variables by using the [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cpowershell#set-variables-in-scripts) to set the variables again in Azure Devops pipeline.

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable={variableName}]{updateValue}"
```

To set a variable from a script, you use the `task.setvariable` logging command. This doesn't update the environment variables, but it does make the new variable available to downstream steps within the same job. In addition ,here is a [reference](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/how-to-pass-variables-in-azure-pipelines-yaml-tasks-5c81c5d31763).